# Pandas - getting NaN after merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes - **df** and **stratnum** that I'm trying to merge. Both have a matching 'STRAT' column:

```
df.dtypes
Out[51]: 
index     float64
BHID     category
FROM      float64
TO        float64
FE        float64
SIO2      float64
S         float64
HEM_R     float64
QTZ_R     float64
PYR_R     float64
STRAT    category
WEATH     float64
dtype: object

stratnum.dtypes
Out[52]: 
STRAT       category
stratnum       int32
dtype: object
```

I tried merging those two dataframes but got a whole lot of NaNs. First I thought that dtypes were a problem - in both dataframes **STRAT** was of `object` dtype and `stratnum` was too.

So I converted both 'STRAT' to `category` and stratnum to `int`. Still, if I run:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, stratnum, how='left', on='STRAT').reset_index()

df2.head(5)
Out[53]: 
   level_0  index     BHID  FROM    TO    FE   SIO2      S      HEM_R  \
0        0    1.0  EMS0417   0.0   2.0  32.7  39.62  0.019  30.169856   
1        1    2.0  EMS0417   2.0   4.0  34.9  38.16  0.021  34.454128   
2        2    3.0  EMS0417   4.0   6.0  38.7  32.92  0.023  37.480192   
3        3    4.0  EMS0417   6.0   8.0  42.4  28.77  0.011  43.541773   
4        4    5.0  EMS0417   8.0  10.0  47.8  21.84  0.015  55.299471   

       QTZ_R     PYR_R STRAT  WEATH  stratnum  
0  32.160097  0.035545   TD3    0.0       NaN  
1  31.218645  0.039287   TD3    0.0       NaN  
2  25.931527  0.043029   TD3    0.0       NaN  
3  22.559341  0.020579   TD3    0.0       NaN  
4  15.487928  0.028062   TD3    0.0       NaN
```

I get a whole bunch of NaNs in stratnum column, while in the original `stratnum` dataframe it's all fine:

```
tratnum.head(5)
Out[54]: 
  STRAT  stratnum
0   D1       5610
1   D2       5620
2   D3       5630
3   D4       5640
4   WL       5710
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: There appears to be some issue with my data. If I try to filter **stratnum** dataframe for 'TD3' for example:

```
test = stratnum[['STRAT']=='TD3']
...
KeyError: False
```

At the same time if I just view the dataframe it is there (#71):

```
stratnum

Out[74]: 
     STRAT  stratnum
0      D1       5610
1      D2       5620
2      D3       5630
3      D4       5640
...
69    TD1       8110
70    TD2       8120
71    TD3       8130
72     UN       9999
73      W       5700
```

Could this be happening because I'm getting data from excel spreadsheet and it has some weird encoding?

**EDIT2:** Changed encoding of the original excel spreadsheet to UTF-8, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it is because of int32? try changing it to int64 before merging.

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: If use `df2 = pd.merge(df, stratnum, how='inner', on='STRAT')` for inner join, it working? There is at least one matched values?

Comment: No, 'inner' returns a completely empty dataframe

Comment: I've done some more checks and something strange is happening with the data, see **EDIT** section of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!
It was strange. I did specify that I wanted excel file to save in **utf-8** encoding, but when I tried to export it to **csv** the resulting file had a whole bunch of **ÿ** characters. For example, that *TD3* I was trying to find looked like *ÿTD3ÿ*.

I quickly used find and replace to delete all special characters, saved csv and now merging works as intended!